# Resolved topic indicator

Tags: support

Hi I was wondering if you could add some indicator near to the question titles. It could be something like :

```
 [Resolved]
```

if the question owner has accepted an answer. That would save time and if people still want to add something they could do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not needed. Questions with an accepted answer are marked as such with a green box in the topic list, and on the topic page the accepted answer is marked with a green check mark.

[image]

Also, people can already add better answer if they have some.

Comment: I'm talking about the page with all questions, I know people can add better answer, I was just implying my change would not affect this functionality.

Comment: @JMa See the attached screenshot. Answered questions are very easy to spot already.

Comment: I missed that sorry but what if I'm daltonian?

Comment: You would still notice the darker background. The brightness contrast in this place is much better than in many other places in our layout.

Comment: thanks a lot and sorry I missed that again.